# Bind to the difference of two Properties from two different ViewModels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I have two viewmodels (each with thier own models):
AmendmentViewModel
YearViewModel

each have a property:
AmendmentViewModel.TotalAmended
YearViewModel.TotalCommitted

On the view there is a TabControl and each of the viewmodels is the datacontext for a tabcontrol page. Yes i know I could technically use one view model but its a LOT of code and a large view that **Has** to be in a tabcontrol.

How do i set the binding of a TextBox to the sum of AmendmentViewModel.TotalAmended & YearViewModel.TotalCommitted ?

Comment: Are you using a specific framework to help you out such as Prism or MVVM Toolkit?

Comment: Where exactly is your TextBox? Is it in one of the TabItem's or is it outside the TabControl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `MultiBinding` together with an `IMultiValueConverter`.  You can find an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx).

**Edit:**

Here's an example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="dataSource1">42</sys:String>
        <sys:String x:Key="dataSource2">22</sys:String>
        <local:SubtractionConverter x:Key="subtractionConverter"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource subtractionConverter}">
                <Binding Path="." Source="{StaticResource dataSource1}"/>
                <Binding Path="." Source="{StaticResource dataSource2}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

and the converter:

```
public class SubtractionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
         return (double.Parse((string)values[0]) - double.Parse((string)values[1])).ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was reading about that but how do I set the DataContext of the same textbox to two different ViewModels as the properties exist in two different view models?

Comment: I added an example.  The binding will depend on how you access your view models.